# Android fragments overlaps after rotation

Tags: android

I am working with fragments. I am using two fragments and its working fine in some cases. After rotation of the device overlapping of fragments data take place in some cases.

However I have tried to save the state of fragments and all. But its not working.

Answer (score 2):

use .replace() on your fragment transaction. It usually solves 90% of overlapping fragments.

Comment: not at all, it makes things more complicated because replace() methode donot remove replaced(old one) fragment from container

Comment: yes it does. That's why it is called 'replace' and that's why the person marked my answer as correct.

Comment: :) ok, maybe you have advise to my problem too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269350/how-to-keep-only-first-initial-fragment-in-back-stack-fragment-overlapping  ?

Comment: I mean, Old fragment View is Destroyed but not Detached on replace() callback.

Comment: I've just answered your question, I'm sure it's the right answer. Check it out.